# Cassandra super column structure

Tags: cassandra, super-columns

I'm new to Cassandra, and I'm not familiar with super columns.

Consider this scenario: Suppose we have a some fields of a customer entity like

- Name
- Contact_no
- address

and we can store all these values in a normal column. I want to arrange that when a person moves from one location to another location (the representative field could store the longitude and latitude) that values will be stored *consecutively* with respect to customer location. I think we can do this with super columns but I'm confused how to design the schema to accomplish this.

Please help me to create this schema and come to understand the concepts behind super columns.

Answer (score 0):

supercolumns are really not recommended anymore...still used but more and more have switched to composite columns.  For example playOrm uses this concept for indexing.  If I am indexing an integer, and indexing row may look like this

```
rowkey =  10.pk56 10.pk39 11.pk50
```

Where the column name type is a composite integer and string in this case.  These rows can be up to about 10 million columns though I have only run expirements up to 1 million my self.  For example, playOrm's queries use these types of indexes to do a query that took 60 ms on 1,000,000 rows.

With playOrm, you can do scalable relational models in noSQL....you just need to figure out how to partition your data correctly as you can have as many partitions as you want in each table, but a partition should really not be over 10 million rows.

Back to the example though, if you have a table with columns numShares, price, username, age, you may wnat to index numShares and the above row would be that index so you could grab the index by key OR better yet, grab all column names with numShares > 20 and numShares < 50

Once you have those columns, you can then get the second half of the column name which is the primary key.  The reason primary key is NOT a value is because as in the example above there is two rows pk56 and pk39 with the same 10 and you can't have two columns named 10, but you can have a 10.pk56 and 10.pk39.

later,
Dean